# WCF Service Interface, when I had a DataSet all my Generic types break

Tags: c#, wcf, strongly-typed-dataset

If I have a Service Interface that has this method:

```
[OperationContract]
Dictionary<string, string> getDictionary();
```

and my client is configured to use Generic Dictionaries, everything is all good. As soon as  I a add a method that accepts or returns a DataSet, my client won't generate Dictionaries, but instead returns ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring. IE:

```
[OperationContract]
DataSet1 howAboutThis();
```

Any ideas? Other people have been running into this soltuion, and it seems microsoft's answer is to not pass DataSets via WCF.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/5df7a37a-c39e-46e2-bc6c-ab7bef37717d

Comment: there is so much overhead in DataSet, are ou sure from a design standpoint that is your best option?  Can you not simplify or decompose the data into something more specfic or granular?

Comment: don't know how to answer in any other way: "microsoft" is right - you should not ... indeed IMHO you should not even pass the dictionary but stupid DTOs ... a dictionary implies functionality that the client will never have after receiving "it"

Comment: Yes, well, my company has inherited a application that was built by 'experts' (paid several million for it) and they have nothing but datasets passed over WCF interfaces. I can work around this issue, but I'm more interested in knowing why this is happening.

Comment: You should blacklist those experts. The only time it makes sense to return a platform-specific type is when you know for certain that hte platform on the client side is the same as the platform on the server side.

Comment: We do know this, the Service Interface will only ever be consumed by .Net sites. If there ever is a case where we need a public facing interface then we would create it as a separate interface and write an adapter. In any case, we all know they made very bad calls in the design of the system, but we're left picking up the pieces and we need to figure out how to deal with their mess.